# How to continue subscribing to publisher after error?

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to set up a publisher that will publish a set of integers and at some point may fail. It's slightly contrived but hopefully illustrates principle. Example below.

```
enum NumberError: Int, Error {
   case isFatal, canContinue
}

struct Numbers {
    let p = PassthroughSubject<Int, NumberError>()

    func start(max: Int) {

        let errorI = Int.random(in: 1...max)
        for i in (1...max) {
            if errorI == i {
                p.send(completion: .failure(NumberError.canContinue))
            } else {
                p.send(i)
            }
        }
        p.send(completion: .finished)

    }
}
```

I then subscribe using:

```
let n = Numbers()
let c = n.p
    .catch {_ in return Just(-1)}

    .sink(receiveCompletion: {result in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            print("Error")
        case .finished:
            print("Finished")
        }
    }, receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    })

n.start(max: 5)
```

This works in that it replaces errors with -1 but I would then like to continue receiving values. Does anyone know if this is possible?
Having read and looked around it seems that flatMap may be the way to go but I can't work out what publisher to use in the closure? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have an incorrect belief that a `PassthroughSubject` can publish more outputs after publishing a failure. It cannot. After you call `p.send(completion: ...)`, any calls to `p.send(...)` will be ignored. Furthermore, if you subscribe to `p` after you call `p.send(completion: ...)`, `p` will immediately complete the new subscription and not send any outputs.

So you can't send your error as `.failure` if you want to send more values after. Instead, change your publisher's `Output` type to `Result<Int, NumberError>` and its `Failure` type to `Never`:

```
import Combine

enum NumberError: Int, Error {
   case isFatal, canContinue
}

struct Numbers {
    let p = PassthroughSubject<Result<Int, NumberError>, Never>()

    func start(max: Int) {
        let bad = (max + 1) / 2
        for i in (1...max) {
            if bad == i {
                p.send(.failure(NumberError.canContinue))
            } else {
                p.send(.success(i))
            }
        }
        p.send(completion: .finished)
    }
}
```

But now you can't use `catch` to handle the error, because it's not coming through as a failure. Instead, you can use `map`:

```
let n = Numbers()
let c = n.p
    .map({
        switch $0 {
        case .success(let i): return i
        case .failure(_): return -1
        }
    })
    .sink(receiveCompletion: {result in
        switch result {
        case .failure:
            print("Error")
        case .finished:
            print("Finished")
        }
    }, receiveValue: {
        print($0)
    })

n.start(max: 5)
```

Output:

```
1
2
-1
4
5
Finished
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation and the alternative approach. Do you by any chance know how the example in WWDC 2019 Combine in practice recovers then? I believe they use flatMap to recover from an encode/decode error.

Comment: In that session, the root publisher is a `NotificationCenter.Publisher`, which never fails. The failure in that WWDC example occurs inside the `flatMap` and is recovered using `.catch` inside the `flatMap`. The failure doesn't escape the `flatMap`. In your question, your root publisher is a `PassthroughSubject` and you send a failure through it.